# JSON only showing last optional in all cells Swift 4

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift4

So the code posted below is my stuct

```
 struct AnimeJsonStuff: Decodable {
    let data: [AnimeDataArray]
}

struct AnimeLinks: Codable {
    var selfStr   : String?

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case selfStr     = "self"
    }
}
struct AnimeAttributes: Codable {
    var createdAt   : String?
    var slug : String?
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case createdAt     = "createdAt"
        case slug = "slug"
    }
}
struct AnimeRelationships: Codable {
    var links   : AnimeRelationshipsLinks?

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case links     = "links"
    }
}

struct AnimeRelationshipsLinks: Codable {
    var selfStr   : String?
    var related   : String?

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case selfStr     = "self"
        case related     = "related"
    }
}

struct AnimeDataArray: Codable {
    let id: String?
    let type: String?
    let links: AnimeLinks?
    let attributes: AnimeAttributes?
    let relationships: [String: AnimeRelationships]?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case type = "type"
        case links = "links"
        case attributes = "attributes"
        case relationships = "relationships"
    }
}
```

This code is my function for parsing data:

```
    func jsonDecoding() {

    let jsonUrlString = "https://kitsu.io/api/edge/anime"

    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else {return}
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
        guard let data = data else {return}
        do {
            let animeJsonStuff =  try JSONDecoder().decode(AnimeJsonStuff.self, from: data)
            for anime in animeJsonStuff.data {
                //   print(anime.id)
                //    print(anime.type)
                //   print(anime.links?.selfStr)
                let animeName = anime.attributes?.slug
                print(animeName)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.nameLabel.text = animeName
                }

                for (key, value) in anime.relationships! {
                    //   print(key)
                    //   print(value.links?.selfStr)
                    //    print(value.links?.related)
                }
            }
        } catch let jsonErr {
            print("Error serializing json", jsonErr)
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

This is what the console prints out:

```
Optional("cowboy-bebop")
Optional("cowboy-bebop-tengoku-no-tobira")
Optional("trigun")
Optional("witch-hunter-robin")
Optional("beet-the-vandel-buster")
Optional("eyeshield-21")
Optional("honey-and-clover")
Optional("hungry-heart-wild-striker")
Optional("initial-d-fourth-stage")
Optional("monster")
Optional("cowboy-bebop")
Optional("cowboy-bebop-tengoku-no-tobira")
Optional("trigun")
Optional("witch-hunter-robin")
Optional("beet-the-vandel-buster")
Optional("eyeshield-21")
Optional("honey-and-clover")
Optional("hungry-heart-wild-striker")
Optional("initial-d-fourth-stage")
Optional("monster")
Optional("cowboy-bebop")
Optional("cowboy-bebop-tengoku-no-tobira")
Optional("trigun")
Optional("witch-hunter-robin")
Optional("beet-the-vandel-buster")
Optional("eyeshield-21")
Optional("honey-and-clover")
Optional("hungry-heart-wild-striker")
Optional("initial-d-fourth-stage")
Optional("monster")
```

It now displays the text but it only displays the last optional called monster and not all the other ones when I have three cells. It only displays monster in each cell. 
It should be

1st cell: Cowboy-bebpop
2nd cell: cowboy-bebop-tengoku-no-tobira
3rd cell: trigun
and etc

Table view methods:

```
     let nameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = UIColor.black

        return label
    }()
    let profileImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        return imageView
    }()

    let synopsis: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = UIColor.black

        return label
    }()


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
        jsonDecoding()
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.05
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 0.05
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 1



    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setupViews() {
        backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.86, green:0.87, blue:0.89, alpha:1.0)
         addSubview(nameLabel.self)
          addSubview(synopsis.self)
        addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|-18-[v0]|", views: synopsis)
        addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|-8-[v0]|", views: synopsis)
        addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|-12-[v0]|", views: nameLabel)
    }
}

extension UIColor {

    static func rgb(_ red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat) -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: red/255, green: green/255, blue: blue/255, alpha: 1)
    }

}

extension UIView {

    func addConstraintsWithFormat(_ format: String, views: UIView...) {
        var viewsDictionary = [String: UIView]()
        for (index, view) in views.enumerated() {
            let key = "v\(index)"
            viewsDictionary[key] = view
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
    }

}
```

Cell functions:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        navigationItem.title = "Kitsu - Your anime feed"

        collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.09, green:0.13, blue:0.19, alpha:1.0)
        collectionView?.register(viewControllerCells.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    }


        override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 350, height: 150)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return  UIEdgeInsets(top: 15, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: where is your `nameLabel` in tableView or CollectionView?

Comment: how can I access that if its in a diff class I know about Global variables but I'm not quite sure how this would work.

Comment: It seems that there is flaw in your design. You are calling `jsonDecoding` in cell. This is not required. You can call it in ViewDidLoad and save the data into arrays. You can set data to collection cell in collection view `cellForItemAt`.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46425131/how-can-i-parse-each-items-into-its-on-uicollection-view-cell/46432873#46432873

Answer (score 0):

If your jsonDecoding() func is placed in each cell, it will fetch all items, then in the for cycle inside, it will cycle through each fetched item changing the label from first to the last. Once reached the last the label will never change anymore.