# How can I parse each items into it's on uicollection view cell

Tags: ios, json, swift, uicollectionviewcell, swift4

So below is my code for parsing JSON and putting it into a collection view cell

```
    import UIKit

let cellId = "cellId"

struct AnimeJsonStuff: Decodable {
    let data: [AnimeDataArray]
}

struct AnimeLinks: Codable {
    var selfStr   : String?

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case selfStr     = "self"
    }
}
struct AnimeAttributes: Codable {
    var createdAt   : String?
    var slug : String?
    let synopsis: String?

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case createdAt     = "createdAt"
        case slug = "slug"
        case synopsis = "synopsis"

    }
}

struct AnimeRelationships: Codable {
    var links   : AnimeRelationshipsLinks?

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case links     = "links"
    }
}

struct AnimeRelationshipsLinks: Codable {
    var selfStr   : String?
    var related   : String?

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case selfStr     = "self"
        case related     = "related"
    }
}

struct AnimeDataArray: Codable {
    let id: String?
    let type: String?
    let links: AnimeLinks?
    let attributes: AnimeAttributes?
    let relationships: [String: AnimeRelationships]?


    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case type = "type"
        case links = "links"
        case attributes = "attributes"
        case relationships = "relationships"

    }
}

class OsuHomeController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        navigationItem.title = "Kitsu - Your anime feed"

        collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.09, green:0.13, blue:0.19, alpha:1.0)
        collectionView?.register(viewControllerCells.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)



    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 350, height: 150)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return  UIEdgeInsets(top: 15, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}

class viewControllerCells: UICollectionViewCell {

    func jsonDecoding() {

        let jsonUrlString = "https://kitsu.io/api/edge/anime"

        guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else {return}
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
            guard let data = data else {return}
            do {
                let animeJsonStuff =  try JSONDecoder().decode(AnimeJsonStuff.self, from: data)
                for anime in animeJsonStuff.data {
                    //   print(anime.id)
                    //    print(anime.type)
                    //   print(anime.links?.selfStr)
                    let animeName = anime.attributes?.slug
                    let animeSynopsis = anime.attributes?.synopsis
                    print(animeName)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.nameLabel.text = animeName
                        self.synopsis.text = animeSynopsis

                    }

                    for (key, value) in anime.relationships! {
                        //   print(key)
                        //   print(value.links?.selfStr)
                        //    print(value.links?.related)
                    }
                }
            } catch let jsonErr {
                print("Error serializing json", jsonErr)
            }
            }.resume()
    }

    let nameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = UIColor.black

        return label
    }()
    let profileImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        return imageView
    }()

    let synopsis: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = UIColor.black

        return label
    }()


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
        jsonDecoding()
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.05
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 0.05
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 1



    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setupViews() {
        backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.86, green:0.87, blue:0.89, alpha:1.0)
        addSubview(nameLabel.self)
        addSubview(synopsis.self)
        addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|-18-[v0]|", views: synopsis)
        addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|-8-[v0]|", views: synopsis)
        addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|-12-[v0]|", views: nameLabel)
    }
}

extension UIColor {

    static func rgb(_ red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat) -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: red/255, green: green/255, blue: blue/255, alpha: 1)
    }

}

extension UIView {

    func addConstraintsWithFormat(_ format: String, views: UIView...) {
        var viewsDictionary = [String: UIView]()
        for (index, view) in views.enumerated() {
            let key = "v\(index)"
            viewsDictionary[key] = view
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
    }
```

which works but however instead of putting in all the data like this

```
Optional("cowboy-bebop")
Optional("cowboy-bebop-tengoku-no-tobira")
Optional("trigun")
Optional("witch-hunter-robin")
Optional("beet-the-vandel-buster")
Optional("eyeshield-21")
Optional("honey-and-clover")
Optional("hungry-heart-wild-striker")
Optional("initial-d-fourth-stage")
Optional("monster")
Optional("cowboy-bebop")
Optional("cowboy-bebop-tengoku-no-tobira")
Optional("trigun")
Optional("witch-hunter-robin")
Optional("beet-the-vandel-buster")
Optional("eyeshield-21")
Optional("honey-and-clover")
Optional("hungry-heart-wild-striker")
Optional("initial-d-fourth-stage")
Optional("monster")
Optional("cowboy-bebop")
Optional("cowboy-bebop-tengoku-no-tobira")
Optional("trigun")
Optional("witch-hunter-robin")
Optional("beet-the-vandel-buster")
Optional("eyeshield-21")
Optional("honey-and-clover")
Optional("hungry-heart-wild-striker")
Optional("initial-d-fourth-stage")
Optional("monster")
```

it does it like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGU17.png) which is wrong it should be displaying each show from top to bottom not just the final one. I did ask this question before and they said to put it in the main view did load then return the cell for item at index path with I would guess anime.attrubites.slug which doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: You need to go through some documentation and/or tutorials to get an idea of how to use a table view. Do a search for `populate uitableview with json swift 3` ... you'll find lots and lots of information. (by the way, do **not** create duplicate questions here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check :

OsuHomeController

```
let cellId = "cellId"

struct AnimeJsonStuff: Decodable {
    let data: [AnimeDataArray]
}

struct AnimeLinks: Codable {
    var selfStr   : String?

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case selfStr     = "self"
    }
}
struct AnimeAttributes: Codable {
    var createdAt   : String?
    var slug : String?
    let synopsis: String?

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case createdAt     = "createdAt"
        case slug = "slug"
        case synopsis = "synopsis"

    }
}

struct AnimeRelationships: Codable {
    var links   : AnimeRelationshipsLinks?

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case links     = "links"
    }
}

struct AnimeRelationshipsLinks: Codable {
    var selfStr   : String?
    var related   : String?

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case selfStr     = "self"
        case related     = "related"
    }
}

struct AnimeDataArray: Codable {
    let id: String?
    let type: String?
    let links: AnimeLinks?
    let attributes: AnimeAttributes?
    let relationships: [String: AnimeRelationships]?


    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case type = "type"
        case links = "links"
        case attributes = "attributes"
        case relationships = "relationships"

    }
}

class ViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {


    var isDataLoaded = false
    var animeNames: [String] = []
    var animeSynopsis: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

            self.jsonDecoding()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        navigationItem.title = "Kitsu - Your anime feed"

        collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.09, green:0.13, blue:0.19, alpha:1.0)
        collectionView?.register(viewControllerCells.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

        collectionView?.delegate = self
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return animeNames.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! viewControllerCells
        cell.nameLabel.text = animeNames[indexPath.row]
        cell.synopsis.text = animeSynopsis[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 350, height: 150)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return  UIEdgeInsets(top: 15, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func jsonDecoding() {
        let jsonUrlString = "https://kitsu.io/api/edge/anime"

        guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else {return}
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
            guard let data = data else {return}
            do {
                let animeJsonStuff =  try JSONDecoder().decode(AnimeJsonStuff.self, from: data)
                for anime in animeJsonStuff.data {
                    //   print(anime.id)
                    //    print(anime.type)
                    //   print(anime.links?.selfStr)
                    if let animeName = anime.attributes?.slug {
                        self.animeNames.append(animeName)
                    } else {
                        self.animeNames.append("-")
                    }
                    if let animeSynop = anime.attributes?.synopsis {
                        self.animeSynopsis.append(animeSynop)
                    } else {
                        self.animeSynopsis.append("-")
                    }

                    for (key, value) in anime.relationships! {
                        //   print(key)
                        //   print(value.links?.selfStr)
                        //    print(value.links?.related)
                    }
                }
                self.isDataLoaded = true
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                }
            } catch let jsonErr {
                print("Error serializing json", jsonErr)
            }
        }.resume()
    }   
}
```

viewControllerCells

```
class viewControllerCells: UICollectionViewCell {

    let nameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = UIColor.black

        return label
    }()
    let profileImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        return imageView
    }()

    let synopsis: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = UIColor.black

        return label
    }()


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.05
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 0.05
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 1



    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setupViews() {
        backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.86, green:0.87, blue:0.89, alpha:1.0)
        addSubview(nameLabel.self)
        addSubview(synopsis.self)
        addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|-18-[v0]|", views: synopsis)
        addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|-8-[v0]|", views: synopsis)
        addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|-12-[v0]|", views: nameLabel)
    }
}

extension UIColor {

    static func rgb(_ red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat) -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: red/255, green: green/255, blue: blue/255, alpha: 1)
    }

}

extension UIView {

    func addConstraintsWithFormat(_ format: String, views: UIView...) {
        var viewsDictionary = [String: UIView]()
        for (index, view) in views.enumerated() {
            let key = "v\(index)"
            viewsDictionary[key] = view
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
    }
}
```